# Lodash fp replace in an object's property

Tags: javascript, lodash

I try to run this code for replace some string in an object's property with loadsh.

```
var data = [
   { name: 'test1', value: 'foo - bar' },
   { name: 'test2', value: 'foo - bar' },
   { name: 'test3', value: 'foo - bar' }
]

var newData = fp.compose(
  fp.map('value'),
  fp.replace('/-/gm', '')
)(data)

console.log(newData)
//display : [ undefined,
     undefined,
     undefined,
     undefined,
     ....
   ]
```

but I want :

```
[
  { name: 'test1', value: 'foo  bar' },
  { name: 'test2', value: 'foo  bar' },
  { name: 'test3', value: 'foo  bar' }
]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `replace()` doesn't operate on the property in place, it just returns a new string. I'd expect a result like `['foo  bar', 'foo  bar', 'foo  bar']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extracting an array of the `value` property values, and then you try to replace the array (not the items) using a regex. You need to `_.map()` the array, and perform the replace on each element, using the callback:

```js
var data = [
   { name: 'test1', value: 'foo - bar' },
   { name: 'test2', value: 'foo - bar' },
   { name: 'test3', value: 'foo - bar' }
]

var newData = _.map(({ value, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  value: _.replace(/\s-\s/gm, ' ', value)
}))(data)

console.log(newData);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your exemple, If i had more than one replace can I use compose ?

Comment: You can compose the replace states inside the map - `{ value: compose(replace1, replace2, etc...) }`.